# Connection pooling with jetty server,mysql in spring boot

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot, jetty

I have developed an application with spring boot and jetty server using mysql database. I was to creating connection pooling for the same. I am not getting any direct references as to how to do it. Kindly suggest the methods to achieve it

Comment: Searching for pooling in the doc is not direct enough it seems :-) - Does [this section helps](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-connect-to-production-database)?

Comment: i am not getting an explicit code/section snippet where i can implement the same directly.

Comment: Seriously? The example of configuration in my link creates a connection pool for MysQL. You may want to improve your question then.